# React: Как передать изменяемое значение в дочерний компонент?

Tags: reactjs

Есть родительский компонент, где при вводе меняется `this.state.value`. Это значение мне нужно передать в дочерний компонент  `<Child my={this.state.value} />`, чтобы потом при каждом изменении я мог получить его через `props.value`. Однако, в моем случае не получается. Я вижу `{this.state.value}`, но в дочерний компонент оно попадает один раз.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает такой код:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };
    console.log(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Child {this.props.my.value}</div>;
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name:
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </label>

          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>

        <Child my={this.state.value} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, rootElement);
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Измените с

```
<div>Child {this.props.my.value}</div>
```

На

```
<div>Child {this.props.my}</div>
```

вы передаете значение, а не объект